# javascript replace and slashes

Tags: javascript, replace

I've got a line to flip all slashes in a string and it works great.

```
    **flipSlashes = shortLocString.replace(/\\/g,"/");**
```

But if I want to flip them back, it falls apart. I've tried all of the following. I don't "get" the //g syntax very clearly, so don't know how to troubleshoot it.

```
    **flipSlashes = shortLocString.replace(///g,"\\");**
    **flipSlashes = shortUrlString.replace(/'/'/g,"\\");**
    **flipSlashes = shortUrlString.replace(/&#47;/g,"\\");**
```

Any help appreciated,
dp

Answer (score 3):

use (i.e. / in regex must be escaped using \/)

`flipSlashes = shortLocString.replace(/\//g,"\\");`

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm! thanks a bunch! I need to play around with that syntax. But I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you both ways

```
var shortLocString = "a/b//c/d//e///f////";
var shortLocString1 = shortLocString.replace(/\//g,"\\");
var shortLocString2 = shortLocString1.replace(/\\/g,"/");
```